# How to exclude a number inside 'for'

Tags: c

I got a homework problem. It requires me to make a program that when we input a number of testcase, it will require us to input numbers until 'testcase' times. for example :
Input : 
3
2 5 4
Output :
11  // 11 is sum of 2, 5 and 4.

But, the constraints is, the numbers that we input after the test case must between 2 and 12 only.

I've tried to exclude the number by if, but it still dont work.

```
int main()
{
    long int testcase;
    long int Throws;
    long int SumofDice;
    long int newThrows = 0;

    scanf("%d",&testcase);

    if(testcase <= 2000 && testcase >= 1){
        for(int i = 0; i < testcase; i++) {

        scanf("%d",&Throws); getchar();

        // Cek apakah nilai tersebut dari 2 sampai 12?
        if(Throws <= 12 && Throws >= 2){
            newThrows += Throws;
        } else{
            return 0;
        }
        }
    }
    printf("%ld\n",newHasilLempar);
    getchar();
    return 0;
```

The checkers still consider it wrong.Also, they want the test case is between 1 until 2000

Comment: "between 2 and 12" could be interpreted either as `Throws <= 12 && Throws >= 2` or as `Throws < 12 && Throws > 2`. The specification needs clarification.

Answer (score 3):

Let me introduce you to something call "debugging"

I modified your code by adding 'printf' statements and removing the unecessary 'getchar()'.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long int testcase;
    long int Throws;
    long int SumofDice;
    long int newThrows = 0;
    scanf("%ld",&testcase);

    if(testcase <= 2000 && testcase >= 1){
       for(int i = 0; i < testcase; i++) {
         scanf("%ld",&Throws); //getchar();

         // Cek apakah nilai tersebut dari 2 sampai 12?
         if(Throws <= 12 && Throws >= 2){
             printf("here\n");
             newThrows += Throws;
         } else{
             printf("there\n");
             return 0;
         }
       }
    }
    printf("over\n");
    //printf("%ld\n",newThrows);
    //getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

You will see that your 'if' statement is working as intended. Take the habit of adding "printf" statements to check if your code goes where its supposed to go, especially for 'if', 'for', 'while', 'switch' statements.

Answer (score 0):

The sample code can be like below :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    long int newHasilLempar;
    long int testcase;
    long int Throws;
    long int SumofDice;
    long int newThrows = 0;

    scanf("%d",&testcase);

    if(testcase <= 2000 && testcase >= 1){
        for(int i = 0; i < testcase; i++) {

        scanf("%d",&Throws);

        // Cek apakah nilai tersebut dari 2 sampai 12?
        if(Throws <= 12 && Throws >= 2){
            newThrows += Throws;
        } else{
            return 0;
        }
        }
        printf("%ld\n",newThrows);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But I would like you to pay attention to some validations :

1.) What if you don't enter the value of 'testcase' between 1-2000(I have added print of newThrows just after for loop to overcome this).

2.) What if you don't enter the value of 'Throws' between 2-12.

If the checker is automated they may take these stuff into consideration.